# Convert a time string to military time number

Tags: crystal-reports, timefield

I have two time fields that have time strings in this format: `07:12 PM`. How do I convert them to military time and as a time field so that I use them in formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cDateTime()` can be used to convert a string to a date.

Then you can format it into military time with the Format Field menu. (Select format `13:23`)

---

If you need military time *inside* formulas, and can't just format the outcome, you'd best keep it as a string. Crystal will keep auto-formatting it back to the default format when it performs calculations. But you could convert a standard-time-string to a military-time-string with something like:

```
If ToNumber(Left({yourValue},2) > 12) Then
    CSTR(ToNumber(Left({yourValue},2) - 12) & Mid({yourValue},3,3)

Else If Left({yourValue},2) = "12" And Right({yourValue},2) = "AM"
    "00" & Mid({yourValue},3,3)

Else
    Left({yourValue},5)
```